Edit line space in Mermaid without html
I am doing some SVG graphs for PDF with mermaid (so I desactivated the htmlLabels).
I want to create a space in between the lines because they are to close to each other.
I can't succeed to either edit the line space or insert an empty line in between without html.
code example :
graph TD
%%{init:{
  "theme": "neutral",
  "flowchart": {
    "useMaxWidth": false,
    "htmlLabels": false,
    "curve" : "monotoneY" 
  }
}
}%%
 classDef nodeStyle fill:#f9f9f9,stroke:#333,stroke-width:2px;

    A["line 1\n line 2\n\n line 4"]:::nodeStyle

I tried to insert a non-breaking space.
For me the 2 options are either being able to export the graphs in a word then PDF with html, then it is doable, or find a way without html.
I also looked at this post but I am not experienced enough to understand it.
Thank you
